# Parse a contrived message protocol with first byte data length followed by data

Tags: c, parsing

I think this code to parse a contrived message protocol with first byte data length followed by data is a little ugly.  Has anyone got any suggestions on how to make it more elegant and more robust?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define LENGTHBYTES 1

void splitmessages(unsigned char* bstream, int length);
void printmsg(unsigned char* msg);

int main() {

   unsigned char stream[] = {2, 'A', 'A', 1, 'B', 3, 'C', 'C', 'C', 1, 'D' };
   int len = sizeof(stream) / sizeof(stream[0]);

   printf("\nTest 1 - four messages together\n");
   splitmessages(stream, len); //works

   printf("\nTest 2 - two complete msgs, then 2 complete msgs\n");
   splitmessages(stream, len-2);  //works
   splitmessages(stream+9, 2);

   //split across a message - in data
   printf("\nTest 3 - messages split across data part\n");
   splitmessages(stream, len-4);  //works
   splitmessages(stream+7, 4);

   //split across a message - just after size
   printf("\nTest 4 - messages split just after size part\n");
   splitmessages(stream, len-5);  
   splitmessages(stream+6, 5);

   //split across a message - just before size
   printf("\nTest 5 - messages split just before size part\n");
   splitmessages(stream, len-6);  
   splitmessages(stream+5, 6);

   return 0;
}

void splitmessages(unsigned char* bstream, int length) {
   //Create msg as soon as you have size and save as static
   static unsigned char* msg = 0;
   static int tempbufposition = 0;
   static int tocompletemsg = 0;

   enum STAGE { SIZE, DATA };
   STAGE stage = SIZE;
   int size = 0;

   //adjust stage to DATA if already have start of msg
   if (tocompletemsg != 0)  
      stage = DATA;

   //get cached size
   if(tempbufposition != 0 && msg) 
      size = msg[0];

   for(int i=0; i<length; ++i){
     switch(stage) {
     case SIZE:
       size = bstream[i];
       if(msg) {
            free(msg);
            msg = 0;
            tempbufposition = 0;
            tocompletemsg = 0;
        }
        //re-create complete msg so add 1 byte for size
        msg = (unsigned char*)malloc(size+LENGTHBYTES); 
        msg[0] = size;
        tempbufposition = 1;
        tocompletemsg = size;

        stage = DATA;
      break;
      case DATA:
         //do we have enough data for a complete message
         if(i + tocompletemsg <= length) {
            memcpy(msg+tempbufposition, &bstream[i], tocompletemsg);
            printmsg(msg);
            stage = SIZE;
            i += tocompletemsg-1;
            tocompletemsg = 0;
            tempbufposition = 0;
         } else {
            //add available data
            memcpy(msg+tempbufposition, &bstream[i], length-i);
            tempbufposition +=(length-i);
            tocompletemsg -= (length-i);
            i += (length-i)-1;
         }

           break;
         }
   }   
}


void printmsg(unsigned char* msg) {
   if(msg && *msg) {
       int size = msg[0];
       printf("%d ", msg[0]);
       for(int i = 1; i <= size; ++i)
          printf("%c ", msg[i]);

       printf("\n");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is an alternative example of how messages could be extracted.  Instead of a state machine with saved-state inside your splitmessages function, I have moved the saved-state out of the function into a structure that is passed-in.   I have also checked for unexpected data at the start of the function.  The return value is 0 on failure or the number of bytes consumed from the input stream on success.  I didn't check for size bytes occurring in the wrong place - replace the memcpy with a function that checks the bytes copied for that.

Note that your protocol has to distinguish between data bytes and size bytes. I have arbitrarily made the boundary 32, the first printable char.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>

#define DATA_MIN_VALUE 32
#define DATA_MAX_SIZE  (DATA_MIN_VALUE)

struct message {
    size_t size;
    size_t remaining;
    char data[DATA_MAX_SIZE];
};  
typedef struct message Message;

static inline size_t min(size_t a, size_t b)
{
    return a < b ? a : b;
}

static inline int is_data(unsigned char ch)
{
    return  ch >= DATA_MIN_VALUE;
}

static size_t
get_message(Message *msg, const unsigned char *bstream, size_t length)
{
    size_t len;
    assert(length);

    if ((msg->remaining == 0) && is_data(bstream[0])) {
        /* Data instead of message; caller must handle - eg. discard data up
         * to next message */
        return 0;
    }

    if (is_data(bstream[0])) {
        msg->size = 0;
        msg->remaining = bstream[0];
    }

    len = min(length-1, msg->remaining);

    memcpy(&msg->data[msg->size], &bstream[1], len);
    msg->size += len;
    msg->remaining -= len;

    return len + 1;
}
```

The code should compile but is untested.  Hope it helps to have another perspective.